# Open source Hebrew OCR

Tags: linux, open-source, ocr

Is there any good free Hebrew OCR for Linux? Hocr doesn't count, as it's off such poor quality. I send *computer generated text* (not scanned, just saved as a gif) through it and it can't pick up anything.

[image: image with Hebrew text]

This seems like a fairly straightforward image to OCR. It doesn't look like what passes as a CAPTCHA these days, yet I've heard that OCRs are able to parse them. If so, all the more so this image. There are no curves, lines cutting through text, etc. Yet hocr can't OCR it.

If not, at least something trainable (I give it 500 gifs of letters, and then it will do OCR based on that).

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Could you provide an example image with expected result so we could vet other tools against it?

Comment: Maybe some finetuning was also needed. If you can give him some "advice", f.e. where to look for its lines.

Comment: Did you try tesseract? There are also good tools to train it, for instance http://terese.sourceforge.net/ or more complex ones: http://succeed-project.eu/wiki/index.php/Tesseract_3.02#Training_Tesseract

Comment: @ocr, Did you find something usable over the past 3 years?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I use [**Tesseract**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesseract_(software)). It provides language files for Hebrew language also. Following is an output of the package available on Debian GNU/Linux. This software is licensed under *Apache License, Version 2.0*

```
$ apt search tesseract-ocr-heb
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
tesseract-ocr-heb/oldstable 3.04.00-1 all
  tesseract-ocr language files for Hebrew
```

The core package is [`tesseract`](https://packages.debian.org/buster/tesseract-ocr) and language file for Hebrew is: [**`tesseract-ocr-heb`**](https://packages.debian.org/buster/tesseract-ocr-heb):

> #### Package: tesseract-ocr-heb (1:4.00~git30-7274cfa-1)
>
> **tesseract-ocr language files for Hebrew**
>
> Tesseract is an open source Optical Character Recognition (OCR) Engine. It can be used directly, or (for programmers) using an API to extract printed text from images. This package contains the data needed for processing images in Hebrew language.

To use it, execute the following command:

```
tesseract -l heb /path/to/image.png /path/to/text
```

Here `-l heb` specifies the language, where `image.png` is the image containing Hebrew text. The output will be stored to `text.txt` file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can go ahead and use Tesseract as well, but if the Captcha is a bit advanced you can train a custom model for it using EasyOCR or if the captcha uses a type font that is a bit hard try using Google Cloud Vision OCR.